Is there a native function in Windows, iOS or PHP to create CSR and import an Apple certificate and export it to p12 format?
I have a Macbook that i use purely to run the native Keychain app to download and export Apple certificates in p12 format from my Apple developer account. If i could do this on my Windows pc, iPhone, or best of all, in PHP 8 running on IIS, this would be a big improvement.
PHP has a openssl_csr_new() function to create a certificate signing request, but i am not able to get PHP to login to my apple developer account and download a certificate.
